# Positioning absolute alement inside relative

Tags: html, css

`.about` have `bottom: 0` and `width: 100%`, why its not at the bottom of `.about` and why it not have 100% of that?

Css properites are here

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.here {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hotel-img {
    position: relative; 
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.hotel-rating {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.about {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;   
}
.about a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Html code is here

```
  <div class="here">
        <div class="hotel-img">
            <img src="imglink" alt="">
            <div class="hotel-rating">
               XXXX
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <span>
                <span class="name">Hotel Imperial</span>
                <span class="address">5th Ave</span>
            </span>
            <div class="benefits">
                <span>WiFi</span>
                <span>Pool</span>
                <span>Dinner</span>
            </div>
            <a href="index.php">Buy night from $99 per night</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Full code is here at codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNrvZm

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:relative;` from `.about` and add it to `.here` like so;

```
.here {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be clear where you want to display `<a href="index.php">Buy night from $99 per night</a>` if you want to display it at the bottom of the `.here` div follow the answer provided by @Sean Murrin .But, if you want to display just after ending benefits div you have to make `.about {position:relative}` which you have already did in your code.
your current code is overlapping because `position: absolute; bottom:0;` means it will start just after ending `.benefits div` because about div will also end here. if you provide the height of about div the about div will not end here.
you can provide padding

```
.about {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom:30px; //should be greater then the height of `.about a` so it will not overlap.
}
```

or

```
.about {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        position: relative; 
        height: something px; //define height of about div
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no set heights on any ancestors of `.about` (I suspect that it that what you really meant was the anchor that's the child of `.about` which is `.about a`).

- So I set a solid yet responsive height to `<body>`. **[height: 100vh](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design)**
- Added **[100vw](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design)** to the `<body>` width (not necessary, for problem at hand).
- Added `height: 100%` to `.here` and `.about`. Now every element that contains `.about a` has the height of the viewport.

Btw, I noticed that`.about` is 70% wide and the image is 30% which I assume is what you intended. Unfortunately, `.about a` looks weird since it doesn't cover the entire width of the viewport and it's not centered within the page. I made 2 demos.

I changed the markup on the second demo.

- `<a>` was moved into `.here`, then wrapped in a `<footer>`
- Gave `<footer>` all of `<a>`'s properties and `position: fixed`
- I also set `display: inline-table` for the title, address, and image so they'll play nice.

The following are the links to the 2 demos previously mentioned.

- This **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/01/pen/ZbRZxg?editors=110)** is the fix you requested.
- This **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/01/pen/avKxpb?editors=110#0)** is as the previous demo and `.about a` corrected.